# If I host my nodejs application on Heroku or other hosting platform can I ignore serving my app using HTTPS?

Tags: node.js, ssl, heroku, https, hosting

I have started creating my own nodejs app (for the first time) that I hope to deploy at some point, perhaps to Heroku or another platform.

I need for my app to encrypt traffic namely for user passwords and sessions (note there is no other obviously sensitive data).

I started looking into serving my app using HTTPS (SSL) however I am now wondering if I need this. If my app is to be hosted and deployed using Heroku/other platform won't all requests be trafficked through their servers presumably using HTTPS by default? I am guessing that the request will then be routed using HTTP to my application, although I am struggling to understand how this works. Ultimately I would like to know if I can ignore worrying about paying for SSL certification and such like when it will not matter in this hosting environment?

Help much appreciated. Matt.

Comment: You don't have to pay for SSL. https://letsencrypt.org/ is a Linux Foundation project that gives you free ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using heroku then you must be using paid dyno( hobby or professional) and heroku provides free SSL to all paid dynos. Furthermore if you think that at some point you can switch hosting then there is always freessl available via Let's encrypt.

Heroku serves all requests with and without SSL in default herokuapp url.

Answer (score 0):

Use cloudflare free plan. Open a free account in cloudflare, Copy the DNS. Then set the DNS in your domain service provider (godaddy or sth), then change the Cname config for the website inside cloudflare. Now you have a free certificate.